# Replace image in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image

How can I do this:

I have a CHECKMARK image wherein when I click that image, it will be replaced with a LOCK image. How can I do this in jquery and php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('img.checkmark').toggle(function() {
   $(this).attr('src', 'lock.png');
}, function() {
   $(this).attr('src', 'checkmark.png');
});
```

All `img` tags with the `checkmark` class will now have the toggle functionality:

```
<img src="checkmark.png" class="checkmark"/>
```

Comment: So with this, after turning the CHECKMARK image to LOCK, if I click the LOCK image will it convert back to CHECKMARK?

Comment: After converting it to lock image, it won't convert back to checkmark. Why is this so?

Comment: function startproject(id) { $('img.proj_status').toggle(function() { if($(this).attr("src") === "images/lock_closed.png"){ $(this).attr('src', 'images/lock_open.png'); window.location = "startproject.php?id="+ id +"&act=open"; } else { $(this).attr('src', 'images/lock_closed.png'); window.location = "startproject.php?id="+ id +"&act=close"; } }); }

Comment: <input type="button" name="Started" onclick="javascript:startproject(<? echo $rowcheck['id']; ?>)" />

Answer (score 1):

Could use a bit more context, but something like this:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#checkmarkImage').click(function ()
    {
        $(this).attr('src', '/path/to/lock/image.jpg');
    });
});
```